# Stuck on Welcome to Nginx after SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, flask

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install SSL on my [site](http://nickczj.com).
The site doesn't load my page properly after editing the default file as shown below.
Any idea what went wrong?

etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name nickczj.com www.nickczj.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
    }

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}


server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-nickczj.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
    }

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```